# Is it possible to use `ADD` function with DynamoDBMapper save expression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using `DynamoDBMapper` `DynamoDBSaveExpression` to save objects into database and have a specific requirement.

In case object doesn't exist in database I want to insert it, otherwise I want to increase `counter` attached to the object by 1.

There is [`ADD`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax) function which should work for me, but I don't see any way how to use it with `mapper`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to say, if you are trying to implement object versioning, you could just use dynamodbmapper optimistic locking https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html

Comment: Interesting, actually I want to have a counter on a row which would be increased every time I see the same hash + range key, but it seems that versioning would do the same for me. Thanks for the suggestion @Stu